# Customise Login Page Based on Required Roles with Grails Spring Security

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have a grails 2.0 app with the spring-security-core 1.2.6 plugin.  I have different pages that have a @Secured annotation with different roles (ROLE_USER and ROLE_ADMIN).  This works but when I try to access either a user or admin secure page I get redirected to the same login page.  I would prefer to tailor this login page to the roles that was requested.

For example, if a unauthenticated user tries to access a ROLE_USER page, I would include a link to the user signup page, but if they tried to access a ROLE_ADMIN page, it should not.

Is there a way to access the requested roles in the login page, or alternatively a method for getting a list of roles for a given URL?

Comment: If you say the name "Burt Beckwith" 3 times he will appear with the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

To use two different login pages you must create a custom **AuthenticationEntryPoint**.  Here is an example already on SO: [Different login controllers in Grails project with Spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383541/different-login-controllers-in-grails-project-with-spring-security).

To send the user to a different location based on the roles that they have, create your own custom **SuccessHandler** and based on what role the user has send them to a different page.

Here's [a link](http://omarello.com/2011/09/grails-custom-target-urls-after-login/) to a blog post I found.

Hope that helps.