# Different login controllers in Grails project with Spring security

Tags: grails, spring-security

My grails web app has two parts: one for desktop / laptop browsers, one for mobile devices which uses jquery-mobile. The mobile part lives in a subtree /mobile/*. Using spring security I'd like to have different controllers/views for login, logout, etc. I haven't found any useful hints researching this topic on the web.

The only option I can currently think of is to extract the mobile app into a grails project of its own which will then force me to extract common logic into a grails plugin which will then force me to a completely different dev and deployment set up and so on... I'd much rather keep mobile and non-mobile part in the same app but cannot figure out how.

Any suggestions appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one again...

I have been working on something similar lately as well.  And had the same 'wants' as you.  Here is what I ended up with.

To point to different login screens I overwrote the AuthenticationEntryPoint step of the security filter chain (spring security).  I used the same logic that the spring-mobile plugin uses.  (In fact, you will have to have spring-mobile plugin installed for this to work)  The deviceResolver is wired up by that plugin.

```
package com.myapp.security

import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.AjaxAwareAuthenticationEntryPoint
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestimport javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException

class MyAppAuthenticationEntryPoint extends AjaxAwareAuthenticationEntryPoint {
    def mobileLoginFormUrl
    def deviceResolver

    @Override
    protected String determineUrlToUseForThisRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException e) {
        if (deviceResolver.resolveDevice(request).isMobile())
        {
             return mobileLoginFormUrl
        }
        return super.determineUrlToUseForThisRequest(request, response, e)
    }
}
```

Wired like so in resources.groovy

```
authenticationEntryPoint(com.myapp.security.MyAppAuthenticationEntryPoint) {
    loginFormUrl = conf.auth.loginFormUrl
    forceHttps = conf.auth.forceHttps
    ajaxLoginFormUrl = conf.auth.ajaxLoginFormUrl
    useForward = conf.auth.useForward
    portMapper = ref('portMapper')
    portResolver = ref('portResolver')
    deviceResolver = ref('deviceResolver')
    mobileLoginFormUrl = conf.auth.mobileLoginFormUrl
}
```

Config lines in Config.groovy

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.auth.loginFormUrl = '/register'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.auth.mobileLoginFormUrl = '/mobile/login'
```

I have also written my AuthenticationSuccessHandler step to force mobile users to the mobile landing page after login.

```
package com.myapp.security

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.AjaxAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler
import org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCache

class MyAppAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends AjaxAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    def mobileTargetUrl
    def deviceResolver
    RequestCache requestCache

    @Override
    protected String determineTargetUrl(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
         if (isMobile(request))
         {
             return mobileTargetUrl
         }
         return super.determineTargetUrl(request, response)
    }

    @Override
    void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, org.springframework.security.core.Authentication authentication) {        
        if (isMobile(request))
        {
            // we always want to go to the mobile landing page here.
            requestCache.removeRequest(request, response);
        }
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication)
    }

    private boolean isMobile(request) {
        deviceResolver.resolveDevice(request).isMobile()
    }

    @Override
    void setRequestCache(RequestCache requestCache) {
        super.setRequestCache(requestCache)
        this.requestCache = requestCache
    }

}
```

This doesn't stop the user from browsing to a non-mobile page, but it does force them to the /mobile/index after login.  Form there all my links on my mobile pages refer to other mobile pages.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate example. I will try it when I'll run into the problem again. This time I took the long way and split the project up into one plugin (containing mainly the domain classes) and two grails projects (one for mobile and one for other devices). This took an afternoon but it now allows me to go with standard configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I would do one of these two options:

- Have a default controller which will redirect to `mobileLogin` or `login` controller based on client browser (or something else)
- Use one login controller but customise display with CSS (and then you can do redirection to desktop/mobile controllers if you have to in your `defaultTargetUrl`)

Comment: Tried your first option but couldn't find the right thing to dispatch on. It should redirect to mobile if the redirect url is within the mobile/ branch. 'params.redirect' is null and the request does not seem to contain the redirection url either.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the spring-mobile plugin?

Allows you to do something like the following in your controllers where you need to switch between standard and mobile.

```
def login() {
    def view = 'login'

    withMobileDevice {
      view = 'mobile/login'
    }

    render view: view
}
```

Comment: yes, I've seen the plugin. Same point as above applies: I don't want to call a different view depending on the device but for a certain sub-part of the website.